# Flask app not able to find installed modules

Tags: python, flask

I have a very basic Flask app with some other Python modules installed, however upon trying to start the app I keep getting `ModuleNotFound` errors. I have attempted to run the app on two difference machines, a laptop running macOS and a PC running Windows and both give me `ModuleNotFound` errors, although they are for different packages.

The error is specifically happening on this line:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

and this is the error:

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 218, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/path/to/project/app.py", line 21, in <module>
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 326, in init_app
    engines[key] = self._make_engine(key, options, app)
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/extension.py", line 614, in _make_engine
    return sa.engine_from_config(options, prefix="")
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 804, in engine_from_config
    return create_engine(url, **options)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 283, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 601, in create_engine
    dbapi = dbapi_meth(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/path/to/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/pymysql.py", line 75, in import_dbapi
    return __import__("pymysql")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

Here is my entire `app.py` file:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

from models import User


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    """Loads the user when given their ID."""
    return User.query.get(int(id))


# Home page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Renders the index page."""
    return render_template('main/index.html')


# Blueprint imports from each package
from users.views import users_blueprint

# Registering each blueprint so that it can be rendered and shown
app.register_blueprint(users_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am using PyCharm as an IDE and can confirm that all the packages have been successfully installed. This is my requirements.txt:

```
Flask
flask_login
flask_wtf
flask_sqlalchemy
SQLAlchemy==2.0.12
python-dotenv==1.0.0
```

I do not know much about how Python and pip works with virtual environments so I am not sure what information to provide.

Comment: Can you provide your complete code and error messages?

Comment: Are these installed outside or inside of your virtual environment?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy I have added my `app.py` file

Comment: @EjazAli I am honestly not sure, I am a beginner when it comes to Python

Comment: Can we see the whole error output? It provides very useful output :)

Comment: Try running `pip install pymysql` or using PyCharm's package installer to install `pymysql`.

Comment: I have provided the entire error message, hope that helps! I have installed and reinstalled all the packages using pip and using PyCharm and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you install a MySQL connector?  SQLAlchemy knows how to talk to database providers, but it can only connect to providers that you have already installed.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have not, could you provide a resource on how to do that if you think it could solve my issue?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy told you exactly how to do that.

Comment: If you mean installing the `pymysql` package, I have already done that to no avail

Comment: Have you installed it inside of your virtual environment? Try that if you're using virtual environments.